# is there way to get numbers from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

it is a weird situation.
The table get id contacts.
I am now get ticket trace which contains several ids here and I want to sum their contacts in total.

[image]

I am trying to make id and contacts into dictionary but I am having hard time to get values things I turn it into a list in each row of the trace list.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include the code you are executing to get this dataframe?

Comment: Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then aggregate sum:

```
df1 = (df.explode('ticket_trace_list')
         .groupby('ticket_trace_list', as_index=False)['Contacts'].sum())
```